# How to invalidate Bitbucket's Pipeline node cache if package.json is changed

Tags: caching, bitbucket, continuous-deployment, bitbucket-pipelines

Currently, I'm caching `node_modules` on Bitbucket which doesn't get cleared even if `package.json` is changed. I have found [Clear caches pipe](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines/integrations?p=atlassian/bitbucket-clear-cache) which automatically clears cache. Is it possible to run this pipeline based on the condition that `package.json` is changed?

Comment: There is a similar issue in Atlassian's Jira, but there is no definitive solution for this problem https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Node-Cache-shouldn-t-persist-when-there-is-a-change-in/qaq-p/1089674